# WSL service logging like journald

Tags: logs, services, init, windows-subsystem-for-linux, systemd-journald

I am running a WSL instance on my machine which starts a bunch of services like `atd`. What I would like to have is to have an ability to lookup the logs of a specific service like I would do using `journalctl` on a standalone Linux Machine. Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I could personally use some more detail.  What distribution are you using (may matter, may not)?  How are you starting the services?  SysVInit scripts manually?  Through `/etc/wsl.conf` (on Windows 11)?  Are the services doing any logging now?  If you can provide some more detail on your preferred workflow with `journalctl`, I *might* can come up with some alternatives.